# Method does not exist or incorrect signature...why?

Tags: apex, trigger

I've got the following class:

```
public class PopulateHasChildAccount {

public Boolean checkForChildren(Account acct) {
    List<Account> childAccounts = [Select Id
                                   From Account
                                   Where ParentId = :acct.Id];
    if(childAccounts.size() > 0) {
        return True;
    }
    else {
        return False;
    }
}
}
```

...and the following Trigger:

```
trigger PopulateHasChildAccountTrigger on Account (after update, after delete, after undelete) {

if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
    for(Account a : Trigger.new) {
        Account oldParent = new Account(Id = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).ParentId);
        Account newParent = new Account(Id = Trigger.newMap.get(a.Id).ParentId);
        Boolean hasOtherChildren = PopulateHasChildAccount.checkForChildren(oldParent);

        //more code
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
```

But I'm receiving the following error when trying to save the Trigger: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: PopulateHasChildAccount.checkForChildren(Account)"

I don't understand why. The class is public, the method is public and the class is instantiated. I'm very new to coding in general and Apex specifically. I keep seeing resolutions for this error saying to make the method static...but then I get an error saying constructors can't be static. In any case, why would it need to be static if I'm instantiating the class that's being passed into the method? (I hope that made sense...I'm never really sure.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark your method as `static`. You have currently defined it as an *instance* method, which would require you to instantiate the object. You *can* instantiate a `PopulateHasChildAccount` instance and then call the method from it, though it doesn't make a ton of sense in this case.

---

**Works (static)**

This approach is the recommended one:

```
public static Boolean checkForChildren(...)

Boolean hasOtherChildren = PopulateHasChildAccount.checkForChildren(...)
```

**Works (instance)**

This approach will compile but doesn't make a ton of sense:

```
public Boolean checkForChildren(...)

Boolean hasOtherChildren = new PopulateHasChildAccount().checkForChildren(...)
```

---

**Fails (calling instance method statically)**

```
public Boolean checkForChildren(...)

Boolean hasOtherChildren = PopulateHasChildAccount.checkForChildren(...)
```

**Fails (calling static method via instance)**

```
public static Boolean checkForChildren(...)

Boolean hasOtherChildren = new PopulateHasChildAccount().checkForChildren(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try to add static, I get the following error: "Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: checkForChildren(Account)"

But if I remove the Account input, how can I reference the Account I need to use in the SOQL query?

Comment: You can't also change the way you call it. Either call it the way you have it and make it static, or define it the way you have it and call it via an instance. Don't change both. @Mike See my updated examples.

Comment: Thanks, got it all saved now. I was seeing the "Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: checkForChildren(Account)" error when trying to save the Class (not the Trigger), not realizing that the error was referencing the Trigger. Once I edited both to match, it saved just fine :)

Comment: Yeah @Mike those cross entity dependencies can be a real pain and puzzle. All too often I find myself comparing what I have in the IDE vs. what's actually in the Sandbox!

Answer (score 1):

this line `public Boolean checkForChildren(Account acct)` should be

```
public Static Boolean checkForChildren(Account acct)
```

Comment: Welcome to the SFSE Reddy. While this is correct, a more detailed answer (like Adrian's) would be far more likely to attract up votes. Generally we try to not only answer but teach at the same time.

Comment: For sure, I try my best next time