# Extension controller unable to pass values to third controller

Tags: apex, controller-extension, compile-error

For some reason I'm unable to pass Task Id and subject to another controller from this extension controller. Any help?

```
public with sharing class MyExtensionController {
        private final Task t;

        public MyExtensionController (ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
            this.t = (Task)sc.getRecord();        
        }


        public static string DoSomething() { 
           MyController.MyMethod(t.Id);        
           return 't.Id';
        }
    }
```

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: t.Id

Please note I want to avoid passing task as a variable to my method "DoSomething". In other words I want to avoid this:

```
public static string DoSomething(Task t) { 
           MyController.MyMethod(t.Id);        
           return 't.Id';
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the opposite mistake as this other question posted at almost the exact same time: [Method does not exist or incorrect signature...why?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160771/method-does-not-exist-or-incorrect-signature-why)

In this case, you have marked the method as `static` when it should be an *instance* method. You can only access instance properties from instance methods. Simply remove the `static` keyword from your method definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is static, so it would not access class level variables as parameters.

Comment: This could be post a comment